# Alter location descriptor passed to <Link> component?

Tags: react-router

I have a React application containing various components which use react-routers Link component.

Say I want to add a query parameter to all links generated by my application. Is there a way to alter all location descriptors passed to Link (to={}) from 1 single location?

Comment: You could either manipulate a state on the parent component and send this setting down to the children via props. Alternatively use a database or something like [tag:react-router-relay] or [tag:redux]

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own link component that does this. There are more considerations than what I am going to address, but the basic idea would be to wrap the `<Link>` component and manipulate the `to` prop passed to your component.

```js
const QueryLink = ({ to, ...rest }) => {
  // ensure that you have a location object
  to = typeof to === 'string' ? { pathname: to } : to
  // update the query object with whatever params you'd like
  to.query = Object.assign({}, to.query, {
    thisWillAlwaysBeAdded: true
  })
  return <Link {...rest} to={queryTo} />
}
```

You would then use your query-injecting link component wherever you were using `<Link>` before. This doesn't take into consideration if there is a `location.search` or if `to` is a string with a `search` string, but that is the general idea.